# Google Cloud Endpoints on Android sometimes gives java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)

Tags: android, google-cloud-endpoints

I am using Google Cloud Endpoints to create a client-server app and I am doing, for now, just the Android version. When I have my device connected to the internet via wi-fi, everything is working as it should. However, when I connect via 3G, sometimes the remote calls to the endpoints API fail with the following stacktrace:

```
java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:552)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:516)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:488)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:240)
at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:163)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:142)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:227)
at libcore.io.Streams.readAsciiLine(Streams.java:201)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponseHeaders(HttpEngine.java:560)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:813)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeTunnel(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:493)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.makeSslConnection(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:463)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl$HttpsEngine.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:442)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:80)
at libcore.net.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:165)
at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:93)
at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
at com.projectbamboo.android.activity.MenuActivity$5.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:175)
at com.projectbamboo.android.activity.MenuActivity$5.doInBackground(MenuActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:131)
at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:513)
... 30 more
```

Here is the code of the request that failed in this situation, but they are all called in the same way and can (and does) happen in any of them:

```
    final LinearLayout list = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.manageGamesLayout);
    list.removeAllViews();
    AsyncTask<Void, Void, CreatedGameList> listCreated = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, CreatedGameList>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            refreshing--;
        }

        @Override
        protected CreatedGameList doInBackground(Void... arg) {

            Gameapi apiServiceHandle = AppConstants.getApiServiceHandle();
            GetCreatedGames function;
            try {
                function = apiServiceHandle.getCreatedGames();
                return function.execute(); // <------ line 175 is here
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(CreatedGameList gamesList) {
            refreshing++;
            List<CreatedGame> list = gamesList.getObjectsList();
            if(list == null)
                return;
            for(CreatedGame game : list){
                addCreated(game);
            }
        }
    };

    listCreated.execute();
```

And here is the AppConstants that is called halfway there:

```
private static GoogleAccountCredential _credential;

public static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new AndroidJsonFactory();

public static final HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();

public static Gameapi getApiServiceHandle() {
    // Use a builder to help formulate the API request.
    Gameapi.Builder helloWorld = new Gameapi.Builder(AppConstants.HTTP_TRANSPORT,
            AppConstants.JSON_FACTORY,_credential).setApplicationName("Project Bamboo");

    return helloWorld.build();
}
```

The device is a Samsung Galaxy S3 mini. When connected via 3G I get ~90ms ping on a normal speedtest and ~10mbit/s download, so it could be much worse.

I would like to know if there is anyway to avoid this problem, or simply how to verify if this situation ocurred to try again a few times or something like that.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

**You might be performing a "Loading request"**

> What is a loading request? Some requests run slower because App Engine needs to create a new Java Virtual Machine (JVM) to service the request.

The quote was taken from [this google page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/java#What_Is_A_Loading_Request)

If the server takes more time to process the request because a new instance is being started combined with the latency in your 3G network could trigger this kind of errors.

**How to test?**

If the error is raised, check if a new instance has been created recently, if so you might want to perform some *warmup requests*

> You can avoid some loading requests by using warmup requests. Warmup requests load application code on a new instance before any live requests are made.

More info on warmup requests [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/java#Warmup_Request)

All the quotes were taken from this google article [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/java)